# How to fix virtualbox startup error: "vboxadd-service ... failed!"

Tags: virtualbox, guest-additions

I'm using VirtualBox 4.0.8 with Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bit host and debian 6.0.1a amd64 guest (in CLI mode).

I installed Guest Additions and it seems to work, at least partially, as I have successfully setup a shared folder between host and guest.

However every time I boot the guest, I get the following messages on console:

```
Starting VirtualBox Guest Addition service ...done.
startpar: services(s) returned failure: vboxadd-service ... failed!
```

There is no additional error message in any of the logs (checked syslog and VBoxGuestAdditions.log)

Additionally, I'm unable to use shared clipboard between host and guest (it's set to bidirectional, but neither direction seems to work). I assume this might be related to the service start failure.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to install VIrtualbox, \`"Specify KERN\_DIR=<directory>"\` -- installing Virtual Box to Debian?](http://superuser.com/questions/499059/unable-to-install-virtualbox-specify-kern-dir-directory-installing-vir)

Answer (score 24):

I faced similar issue. I went through this [Installing Guest Additions on Debian](http://virtualboxes.org/doc/installing-guest-additions-on-debian/). Follow the steps mentioned there. Sometimes missing `build-essential module-assistant` packages cause the issue.

Steps

> 1. Login as `root`
> 2. Update your APT database with `apt-get update`
> 3. Install the latest security updates with `apt-get upgrade`
> 4. Install required packages with `apt-get install build-essential module-assistant`
> 5. Configure your system for building kernel modules by running `m-a prepare`
> 6. Click on Install Guest Additions… from the Devices menu, then run `mount /media/cdrom`
> 7. Run `sh /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`, and follow the instructions on screen

For me it did the trick. :)

Comment: External links can break, in which case your answer wouldn't be useful.  For this reason, we ask that you include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Can you expand you answer?  Thanks.

Comment: @JakeGould it shows that 30 seconds of effort to give a  answer make a big difference, even if is wrong.

Comment: this fixed my tools on Debian 8.5 in VirtualBox 5.1.2

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04, I was getting both `[FAILED] to start Virtualbox guest utils. See 'systemctl status virtualbox-guest-utils.service' for details.` and `[FAILED] Failed to start vboxadd-service.service. See 'systemctl status vboxadd-service.service' for details.`. Following your steps eliminated the first error message but I'm still encountering the second error message, which is the same one that is described in the post. :/

Comment: Disregard that last phrase. I misread the error in the post.

Comment: You da best! Thanks. this fixed my VM boot!

Comment: @FranciscoTapia sorry, I didn't notice the comments. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: Did all that and still getting the same error. I have to say before Debian 10 I have never ever installed (at least not explicitly) `module-assistant`, nor have I ever ran `m-a prepare`.

Comment: i tried installing module-assitant but no change at all, even m-a prepare given no newly updated kernels....

Answer (score 10):

**[disclaimer]** this is an old post, written before systemd and the like. The goal is the same, but removing `/etc/init.d/` files isn't correct, you should use `systemctl disable XXXX` rather than deleting files. **[/disclaimer]**

**[update]** I've also posted a solution here for the error `Failed to connect to the guest property service`: https://github.com/NixOS/nixops/issues/908#issuecomment-387275731

**1)** If you run the `/media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` then you'll have some startup scripts in /etc/init.d that doesn't come with Debian default package.

You should get rid of these: `ls /etc/*/*vbox*` (remove all rcX.d and init.d files with vbox in the filename).

**Important note:** You should also look for already compiled modules:
`find /lib/modules/ -name "vbox*"`
and remove these (based on the assumption that everything was badly installed). If you have multiple files with the same name, that could explain the whole issue (multiple versions of Guest additions are installed).

Or you can simply run: `sh /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run uninstall`.

**2)** Install only the Debian package `virtualbox-guest-dkms`: it seems that VirtualBox doesn't depend on `build-essential` and `module-assistant` but needs both packages (as stated by @gaborous)! So install all three:

`sudo apt-get install build-essential module-assistant virtualbox-guest-dkms`

**3)** To check everything's fine, for example using `systemctl` command, just after removing all traces of the CD-Rom install:

- **vboxadd-service**.service                                                                  **not-found** failed failed    vboxadd-service.service
- **vboxadd**.service                                                                          **not-found** active exited    vboxadd.service
- **virtualbox-guest-utils**.service                                                           loaded    active running   LSB: VirtualBox Linux Additions
- **virtualbox-guest-x11**.service                                                             loaded    active exited    LSB: VirtualBox Linux X11 Additions
- **virtualbox**.service                                                                       **not-found** active exited    virtualbox.service

After restart:

- **virtualbox-guest-utils**.service                                                           **loaded** active running   LSB: VirtualBox Linux Additions
- **virtualbox-guest-x11**.service                                                             **loaded** active exited    LSB: VirtualBox Linux X11 Additions

4) use `systemctl --failed` to list all units that have failed.

And you're back on Debian's wonderful packages :-)

Comment: This fixed my issue. However, there wasn't any file to remove with `ls /etc/*/*vbox*`, but that doesn't matter as installing `virtualbox-guest-dkms` and `apt-get install build-essential module-assistant` fixed the issue on its own, I could boot up correctly in my Debian afterward.

Comment: Note that it's also possible to uninstall the Guest Additions using `sh /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions*/uninstall.sh`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you don't have the multiple copies of the Virtual Box Guest Additions installed. Squeeze will pick up that it is inside a Virtual Box virtual machine and install the 3.x OSE version of the tools automatically.

Comment: I searched for all installed packages via "aptitude search virtualbox", only "virtualbox-ose-guest-dkms" shows up as installed. That should be correct, right?

Answer (score 1):

After uninstalling the packages Debian automatically added for you, remove the services :
`cd /etc/init.d && insserv -r vboxadd vboxadd-service vbox-add-x11`

This removed the startup services for me. However, the scripts are still there. If you want to remove them :
`cd /etc/init.d && rm vboxadd vboxadd-service vbox-add-x11`

BTW: to uninstall the packages : `dpkg -l | grep virtual`. Then do `apt-get remove --purge <list_of_the_packages>`

In my case :
`apt-get remove --purge virtualbox-ose-guest-dkms virtualbox-ose-guest-utils virtualbox-ose-guest-x11 && apt-get autoremove && apt-get autoclean` did the trick.

Also, for some reasons, I couldn't have the shared folder with Debian's guest additions. So I had to add the ones from Virtual Box. Add the Cd (should be host key + D, I'm running a french version can't tell the english labels). Then mount the cdrom and run the script with :
`mount /media/cdrom && bash /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the same issue by `sudo apt-get install build-essential` (installing dependencies)
and reinstalling guest additions.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall `virtualbox-ose` and reinstall all VirtualBox Debian packages with:

```
aptitude search virtualbox
```

Answer (score 0):

Un-checking the Guest Additions iso from Devices may help you - it did for me:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround for when you have no access to the command-line. I was encountering the error on startup, so I didn't have access to any command-line interface and all suggested commands through googling didn't work.

This helped me:

- Updated VBox from 5 to 6
- Created a new VM with the old VM `.vdi` volume.

And the vbox service error was fixed! (Maybe it could even be fixed just by the second step!)